# How to fix 'Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"username"}'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pythonanywhere

My Python code is working totally fine in my PC,
but when I uploaded it in server it shows error. 
Please see the code its easy to read

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
import time

with Display():

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()


try:

    browser.set_window_size(1080,800)

    browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')

    print (browser.title)

    time.sleep(5)

    # i used the screenshot to cheek the problem , but the screenshot is totally
    # blank (just a whit screen )  

    browser.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
    print("clicked..!")
    browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys('*****')
    browser.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys('*****')

finally:
    browser.quit()
```

Login • Instagram
clicked..!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Sourabh58/bot1.py", line 25, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys('be_fully_motivated')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 365, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"username"}
```

Comment: Just wait for the page to load i think in the server page was not loaded. Add a method to check if the page is loaded or not, after that do the operation.

Answer (score 1):

Using [time.sleep()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_sleep) is a some form of an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern#Programming) as your test will wait for 5 seconds even if the element appears in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) faster.

Consider refactoring your code to use [Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead, this way WebDriver will poll the DOM for the element presence (or absence) and continue immediately after the element is found.

Suggested code change:

```
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')

username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'username')))
username.send_keys("****")
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password')))
password.send_keys("****")
```

this `10` stanza stands for 10 seconds of maximum wait time, you can increase/decrease it according to your test scenario, network bandwidth, application response time, etc.

More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)